# XSLT Transformation- com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.ClassGenException: Not targeting 24730: nop[0](1), but null

Tags: java, xml, xslt

**Migration from Java 8 to Java 11**
XSLT is used to transform the response getting below error.
Please let us know what is causing this problem. It works fine with Java 8.

XSLT file and XML content is big in size.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {
    String data = readFileAsString("Sample.xml");
    String dataxsl = readFileAsString("Test.xsl");
    transform(data, dataxsl);
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
 public static String readFileAsString(String fileName) throws Exception {
    String data = "";
    data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
    return data;
}

public static String transform(String dataXML, String inputXSL) throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {

        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File(inputXSL));
        Source text = new StreamSource(new File(dataXML));
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
        StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(out));
        return out.toString();

    }
```

com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.ClassGenException: Not targeting 459415: nop0, but null   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.BranchInstruction.updateTarget(BranchInstruction.java:217)     at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.util.MethodGenerator.outline(MethodGenerator.java:1721)    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.util.MethodGenerator.outlineChunks(MethodGenerator.java:1168)  at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.util.MethodGenerator.getGeneratedMethods(MethodGenerator.java:1882)    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.util.ClassGenerator.addMethod(ClassGenerator.java:137)     at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Mode.compileNamedTemplate(Mode.java:536)   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Mode.compileTemplates(Mode.java:545)   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Mode.compileApplyTemplates(Mode.java:804)  at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Stylesheet.compileModes(Stylesheet.java:622)   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Stylesheet.translate(Stylesheet.java:735)  at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:503)  at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:570)  at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1018)  at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:817)

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: Also, add your Java code to the original question.

Comment: Also, a stacktrace starts with an exception, which is not part of your post.

Comment: This is an internal bug within the XSLT processor, so a bug report to Oracle may be a better way forward than raising a question here. Unless by chance someone else has come across the same bug.

Comment: The stacktrace is truncated at the top. It misses the actual exception

Comment: Add more details to issue